# Canvas animation pixelated

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I want to animate an Arc on Canvas, and it works (with a really basic animation, interval), but the outcome is very pixelated/edgy. On the left side I draw an arc (animated), on the right side without animation (smooth).

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C8CXz/2/

```
 function degreesToRadians (degrees) {
   return degrees * (Math.PI/180);     
 }

 function radiansToDegrees (radians) {
   return radians * (180/Math.PI);
 }

 var canvas = document.getElementById('circle');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var start = 0, end = 0;
 var int = setInterval(function(){
     end++;
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(80, 80, 50, degreesToRadians(0)-Math.PI/2, degreesToRadians(end)-Math.PI/2, false);
     ctx.lineWidth = 10;
     ctx.stroke();
     if(end >= 360) {
         clearInterval(int);    
     }
 }, 10);

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(220, 80, 50, degreesToRadians(0)-Math.PI/2, degreesToRadians(360)-Math.PI/2, false);
 ctx.lineWidth = 10;
 ctx.stroke();
```

(raw simple code, dont mind the sloppiness)

Answer (score 1):

You need a:

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
```

In each draw loop.

Basically, you are drawing the same arc over itself hundreds of times.  The edge pixels that are only partially black are bing darkened over and over until they are completely black.

Things like this are way nearly all canvas animations clear the canvas and draw fresh for each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing the drawing rectangle on every frame

```
    ctx.clearRect(x,y,width,height);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C8CXz/3/

Answer (score 0):

I found that I first need the clear the canvas.

```
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```